# Question about lyrics meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

Once I listened to a song and there were some strange words that I can't understand. I have searched for the [lyrics](http://www.releaselyrics.com/394f/conjure-one-sleep/) and found various [results](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugnv-h343gI):

> 1. My nervous system is shot all right.
> 2. My nervous system is shut all right.

Which one is right? Is it an idiom? How could I better understand it, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

There is an idiom; *my nerves are shot to pieces*, or similar wording.  It refers to a state of being very nervous, lacking in confidence.

The derivation is from the First World War when soldiers who experienced trench warfare suffered from Shell Shock, a mental condition resulting in, amongst other things, extreme nervousness.

Comment: OED's first citation for the relevant figurative usage is *1926   E. Hemingway **Fiesta** (1927) iii. xix. 277   **That meant San Sebastian all shot to hell**.* But I found this from 1846: [***His nerves are shot away**, — his spirits consumed, he must strike, and careen his shattered bark under the genial air and early hours*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nerves+are+shot%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22nerves+are+shot%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899). Whichever way you look at it, "derivation is from the First World War" seems unlikely.